# UIPickerView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I have a label that I want programmatically add a birthdate from my user, I manage to populate with data, but I can't extract data correctly, here is my code: that show an error like the index is out of range, and crash my app

```
class SignUpFormViewController: UIViewController {

    let date = Date()
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    let years = (1800...2100).map{String($0)}
    let days = (1...31).map{String($0)}
    var pickerMonth: [String] = [String]()
    var pickerDay: [String] = [String]()
    var pickYears: [String] = [String]()

    var selectedMonth: String?
    var selectedDay: String?
    var selectedYear: String?

//other stuff

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        handleGestureRecognizer()
        self.datePickerView.delegate = self
        self.datePickerView.dataSource = self
        datePickerComponents()
    }

}

extension SignUpFormViewController: UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 3
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {

        if component == 0 {
            return pickerMonth.count//month
        }else if component == 1 {
            return pickerDay.count//day
        }else {
            return pickYears.count//year
        }
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {

        if component == 0 {
            return pickerMonth[row]
        }else if component == 1 {
            return pickerDay[row]
        }else {
            return pickYears[row]
        }
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

        birthDateTextField.text = "\(pickerMonth[row])/\(pickerDay[row])/\(pickYears[row])"
    }

    func datePickerComponents() {
        pickerMonth = formatter.shortMonthSymbols
        pickerDay = days
        pickYears = years
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    birthDateTextField.text = "\(pickerMonth[row])/\(pickerDay[row])/\(pickYears[row])"
}
```

That's way too simple-minded. Think about it. The user spins only one component at a time, and your method is called. Let's say it's the year component that the user spun. You've got 300 of those. So `row` could be 300 (let's say). But `pickerMonth` doesn't have 300 months in it! So you crash when you naively say `pickerMonth[row]`.

What you want to do is *ask* the picker view what row is selected in all three components and use that row for that component.

```
birthDateTextField.text = 
    pickerMonth[pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent:0)]
    + "/" + 
    pickerDay[pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent:1)]
    + "/" + 
    pickYears[pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent:2)]
```

Comment: Fixed the code. :) Untested still, just typing in SO directly, so do double-check me.

Comment: works perfectly, I recently just began IOS development,  doing a side project besides work, to learn better.